# MySQL - Search for bracket and space in string

Tags: mysql, space, square-bracket

I have a database with names required to be in this format: **FIRST LAST [ID NUMBER]**

These names are entered manually and are sometimes entered incorrectly without the second space like this: **FIRST LAST[ID NUMBER]**

My intent is to search for all instances of the incorrect format. I'm trying to find a way to search the string for an expression containing:

- a left bracket immediately preceded by a letter rather than the required space
- only one space (or two, which I can use with NOT LIKE)
- a space followed by a left bracket, which I can use with NOT LIKE

I've searched extensively, and I've tried several commands such as RLIKE, REGEXP, NOT LIKE, SPACE, etc. I can't get anything to work. Here is just one example I've tried which returns both correct and incorrect entries:

```
SELECT CO.name 'User'
FROM tcompany CO
WHERE CO.name NOT LIKE '%. \\['
ORDER BY CO.name ASC;
```

Comment: `REGEXP NOT '[[:space:]]\\[` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
WHERE CO.name NOT LIKE '% [%'
```

Comment: for completeness, if CO.name can be NULL, we might want to consider a NULL value as also not containing a `' ['` (space and open square bracket characters). To get the entire inverse set to the rows that *do* contain that character sequence, we'd add **`OR CO.name IS NULL`**

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you. you can actually search **NOT** for your desired string and the leftovers are your records that match.

```
SELECT CO.name 'User'
FROM tcompany CO
WHERE CO.name NOT LIKE '(Select CONCAT(FIRST, " " ,LAST) from User) [%%]'
ORDER BY CO.name ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

This was interesting. So to meet your first condition the following will work.

```
SELECT CO.name 'User'
FROM tcompany CO
WHERE CO.name NOT LIKE '%[ ][[]%'
ORDER BY CO.name ASC;
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? `[ ]` is regexp syntax, `LIKE` doesn't treat brackets specially.

Answer (score 0):

Another option specifically to find missing spaces before the left bracket:

```
WHERE SUBSTR(CO.name, LOCATE('[', CO.name) - 1, 1) <> ' '
```

And if you want to correct them:

```
UPDATE tcompany
SET name = REPLACE(name, '[', ' [')
WHERE SUBSTR(name, LOCATE('[', name) - 1, 1) <> ' '
```